# Need to upload directory content to S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

My scenario is I am currently using AWS CLI to upload my directory content to S3 bucket using following AWS CLI command:

```
aws s3 sync results/foo s3://bucket/
```

Now I need to replace this and have python code to do this. I am exploring [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/s3.html) documentation to find the right way to do it. I see some options such as:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ServiceResource.Object

Could someone suggest which is the right approach.

I am aware that I would have to get the credentials by calling `boto3.client('sts').assume_role(role, session)` and use them subsequently.

Comment: I found that the easiest way was just call the cli sync command from python, using e.g. `os.system` as there is no build in function for that in boto3. You have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS CLI is actually written in Python and uses the same API calls you can use.

The important thing to realize is that Amazon S3 only has an API call to **upload/download one object at a time**.

Therefore, your Python code would need to:

- Obtain a list of files to copy
- Loop through each file and upload it to Amazon S3

Of course, if you want `sync` functionality (which only copies new/modified files), then your program will need more intelligence to figure out which files to copy.

Boto3 has two general types of methods:

- `client` methods that map 1:1 with API calls, and
- `resource` methods that are more Pythonic but might make multiple API calls in the background

Which type you use is your own choice. Personally, I find the `client` methods easier for uploading/downloading objects, and the `resource` methods are good when having to loop through resources (eg "for each EC2 instance, for each EBS volume, check each tag").

Comment: Thanks John, For `client` which api calls are you referring to?

Comment: `list_objects_v2()` and `upload_file()`